# How to add multiple elements to the wrappanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to insert several `StackPanel` inside the `WrapPanel` as you can see the XAML below:

Only the `TextBlock` inside the `StackPanel` will be modified so as not to repeat the Title and Text.

```
<Window x:Class="ambient_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ambient_test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
            <WrapPanel x:Name="wrappanel">
                <StackPanel x:Name="panel1" Width="120" Margin="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF38C59F"></StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Title 1" Foreground="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Text 1" Foreground="#FF747474" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0 15 0 0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="panel2" Width="120" Margin="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF38C59F"></StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Title 2" Foreground="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Text 2" Foreground="#FF747474" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0 15 0 0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I created a class called `Info` to change the Title and the Text. In the method constructor I have a for loop that will add 10 contents to the `List`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Info> infos = new List<Info>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        infos.Add(new Info()
        {
            Title = $"title {i}",
            Text = $"text {i}"
        });
    }
}

public class Info
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

For example, my `List` has 100 records, so I need to add 100 `StackPanel` inside my `WrapPanel` following the same Title and Text as the List.

Is there any way to do this? For example using Binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use an `ItemsControl` that uses a `WrapPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`, and defines the layout of the items by an appropriate `DataTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}" .../>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text}" .../>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and assign the `List<Info>` to its ItemsSource property:

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = infos;
```